# Passing ASP.NET values into an external web servers iframe using GET

Tags: c#, php, asp.net-mvc, razor, get

I will be putting a big bounty on this question as it's a service I think people would really be able to leverage.

I have recently wrote a script using ASP.NET MVC/C#. It is simple enough - it displays a frontend for a database of users on a webpage. The entire code can be posted below, it doesn't really need to be read as it is quite simple, but just to give a full background of what I am doing -

Here is the main page of the site :

```
@model IEnumerable<WhoIs.Models.Employee>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contoso Employees";
}
@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
            </hgroup>
        </div>
    </section>
}

      <label for="filter">Enter employee details here : </label>
      <input type="text" name="filter" value="" id="filter" />

<h2><strong>Users</strong> (<a href="/home/create" style="color: blue;">create new</a>)</h2>
<br />

<div style="min-height: 150px; font-size: 1.25em">
    <div style="margin-bottom: .5em">
        <table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Branch</th><th>Phone No.</th><th>Username</th><th>Email</th></tr></thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach ( var prod in Model )
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@prod.FullName</td> 
                        <td>@prod.Branch</td> 
                        <td>@prod.PhoneNo</td> 
                        <td>@prod.DomainAC</td> 
                        <td>@prod.Email</td> 
                        @if (User.IsInRole(@"Admins") || User.Identity.Name == prod.DomainAC) {
                                <td><a href="/home/edit/@prod.Id"  style="color: blue;">edit</a></td>
                         }else{
                         <td>User => @User.ToString()</td>
                        }
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="message" value="@prod.PhoneNo">Message<br></td>
                    </tr>
                 }
                 </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
     </div>

  <div id="iframe2">
        <br />
        <iframe src="http://webaddress.com/web/login.htm" width="400" height="400" />
    </div>
```

This renders a simple page with a list of employees at Contoso, giving Admins and users themselves the ability to edit their details. After this, I have an iframe of a remote web server I do not have control of. The iframe has some input boxes which pass values into a PHP function with a GET. Where the checkboxes are selected above, in my ASP.NET/MVC, I would like to pass the value of the checkbox (the users phone number) into my url/get command.

How can I do this ?

For completeness, although this cannot be edited, the HTML of the iframe looks like :

```
echo "<body>";


echo "<form action=d.php method=get>";


echo "<input type=hidden name=u value=$u>"; <!--Username passed from previous page of iFrame-->
echo "<input type=hidden name=p value=$p>";<!--Password passed from previous page of iFrame-->
echo "<input type=text name=s value=$s>";<!--List of phone numbers-->
```

The PHP in d.php simplifies to :

```
$u = $_GET['u'];
$p = $_GET['p'];
$s = $_GET['s'];
```

So if I put in some values, the URL changes to :

http://webaddress.com/web/d.php?u=112233&p=1234&s=12345678910&m=test

What I want to do is, for each checkbox selected above, append to &s a comma followed by the phone number of the row of the selected user.

So, for instance, if I have this in my  ASP.NET MVC

```
Full Name    Branch    PhoneNo   DomainAC   Email   Checkbox
Test1   Test1   7777777   DOMAIN\TEST1   test1@test1.com   Ticked
```

I would like to run http://webaddress.com/web/d.php?u=112233&p=1234&s=7777777&m=test

If I have another user named "John" with a phone number of 121212, then :

http://webaddress.com/web/d.php?u=112233&p=1234&s=7777777,121212&m=test

Is this possible? How can I do this ?

Comment: Are you just asking how to append query string values to the `src` attribute of an `iframe`?

Comment: @David Not quite, the initial source will be <iframe src="http://webaddress.com/web/login.htm" width="400" height="400" />. The user then logs in, and so the iframe goes to : http://webaddress.com/web/t.php?u=PERSONS-USERNAME&p=PERSONS-PASSWORD. This opens up a new html page with some input boxes. On submit of this new page, I would like to append the selected values from my ASP.NET onto the existing values in the address, so we get : http://webaddress.com/web/d.php?u=PERSONS-USERNAME&p=PERSONS-PASSWORD&s=PHONE-NUMBERS-FROM-ASP-AND-HTML-INPUT-BOX-APPENDED-WITH-COMMAS-DELIMITING&m=test

Comment: It's still not clear what the structure is of these operations.  So there's a login form in an `iframe`, and the user navigates around still within that `iframe`, and you want the parent frame to capture a GET request from within the `iframe` and modify itself in response?  I don't think that's possible.  The parent frame doesn't really know what's going on in the child frame.

Comment: @David Yes, I have an iframe with a log in. The user enters their details. They are logged in. A new form is displayed with some input boxes. I wish to append the selected phone numbers from the ASP.NET to the address being navigated to in the iframe when the user clicks submit :). I think I should be able to create my own HTML form and use the values from this to populate my URL at the very least; I'd just rather a nicer solution than this and I'm not fully sure how to go about doing it this way. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... I've never tried it before, but you might look into whether the `iframe` element exposes any events to the parent frame.  Maybe an `onload` event or something like that?  I don't know of any, but it's worth a try.  If it does then the parent frame's JavaScript might be able to capture those events and modify the `iframe`'s `src` in response.

Comment: @David I could write some HTML input boxes myself and construct the URL I need to run the script on my web server; I think that would be the easiest solution. I'm just not sure how to do this elegantly...or at all! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to manipulate the values of input text fields and checkboxes inside the iframe.

**The simple answer is:**

If the remote domain is different from your hosting domain, it is not possible to call methods or access the iframe's content document directly using javascript. You can use cross-document messaging, but that won't work in this scenario as you cannot change the remote site's source.

If both were on the same domain, this could be accomplished by using javascript. An example of accessing the iframe's document would be:

```
var iframe_doc = document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.document;
```

From there you could transverse the DOM using js as you normally would.